# vxWorks warning: variable <task> is used before its value is set

Tags: c, eclipse, vxworks

This my problem `warning (etoa:4549): variable "T1" is used before its value is set`

[image]

When i run this the `debugger` turn on!

[image]

I don't know what the wrong and i can't run this!

> CPU: Windows 6.1.  Processor #0.  Memory Size: 0x1f00000 (31Mb).  BSP
>   version 6.9/0.  Created: Jul 17 2012, 10:12:44  ED&R Policy Mode:
>   Deployed  WDB Comm Type: WDB_COMM_PIPE  WDB: Ready.

```
-> Exception !
Vector 13 : Access Violation
Program Counter:        0x00000000
Access Address (read):  0x00000000
Status Register:        0x00010246
Task: 0x1044e2d0 "T3"
0x1044e2d0 (T3): task 0x1044e2d0 has had a failure and has been stopped.
0x1044e2d0 (T3): fatal kernel task-level exception!
Exception !
Vector 13 : Access Violation
Program Counter:        0x00000000
Access Address (read):  0x00000000
Status Register:        0x00010246
Task: 0x1044dce0 "T1"
0x1044dce0 (T1): task 0x1044dce0 has had a failure and has been stopped.
0x1044dce0 (T1): fatal kernel task-level exception!
Exception !
Vector 13 : Access Violation
Program Counter:        0x00000000
Access Address (read):  0x00000000
Status Register:        0x00010246
Task: 0x1044dfd8 "T2"
0x1044dfd8 (T2): task 0x1044dfd8 has had a failure and has been stopped.
0x1044dfd8 (T2): fatal kernel task-level exception!
```

Comment: You mean `task_1`? I suggest you follow up the compiler warning, what it says. The warning is because *undefined behaviour* will follow the use of uninitialised variable.

Comment: Bear in mind too, that you have cast `int task_1` as `FUNCPTR(task_1)`

Comment: @ Weather Vane , thank you now is work ... thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variable `int task_1` as well as a function with the same name `void task_1(void)`. So, while you are intending to pass in the function pointer as an argument to `taskSpawn`, you are actually passing in the int variable `task_1` instead. Which results in the warning that you are using `task_1` before it has been assigned.

You should change the names of one of these things, so that there is no conflict.

```
int task_id_1, task_id_2, task_id_3, msgQueueId;

task_id_1 = taskSpawn(..., (FUNCPTR)task_1, ...);
```